# CRM 2011 API call for a view GUID by name

Tags: javascript, ajax, crm

I'm trying to pull back the GUID of a view to set a default lookup value in javascript.  The rest of my code works if I hard code the variables, but that's not good development practice (though, pulling back a unique identifier by querying on a non-unique identifier isn't great either, but its better).  I'm not sure how to form the ajax call though.

Here is a shell of what I am working with, I just don't know what to put at the end of /CRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/  to get the proper record from the API.  The Views are savedquery entities, so /savedquerySet makes sense but I'm not sure how to tell it to look up by name.  I've not used this API a lot, and the documentation is confusing for me.

```
var b = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/savedquerySet (<something here not sure what>)";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "json",
    url: b,
    beforeSend: function (a) {
        a.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    },
    success: function (a) {
        var b = a.d;
        SetGuid(b.SavedQueryIdUnique); // defined function
    }
})
```

the field I am trying to query on is Name.

Help is very appreciated.  This is in CRM 2011 UR 8 or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your REST query should look something like this:

```
/SavedQuerySet?$select=SavedQueryId&$filter=Name%20eq%20'YOUR VIEW NAME HERE'
```

The `SavedQuerySet` name is case sensitive, as well as the attribute name in the `select` (and filter) clause.

See the [MSDN documentation on the ODATA endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx) for details.

Comment: thanks, this is about what I came up with on my own working through it

Comment: What I ended up with is  "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/savedquerySet?$select=SavedQueryId&$filter=Name%20eq%20'" + name + "')";  but it doesn't return anything, and the name is good (copied from DB value).  Not sure where I screwed up

Comment: Make sure you respect the casing for `SavedQuerySet` (uppercase "S" and "Q") ... and there's a dangling bracket ) at the end you don't need. And one more thing I just noticed: You're trying to receive json but ODATA returns Xml! Maybe try the Url in your browser and check the returned page source (this will also allow to verify your query itself)

Comment: yeah I found the bracket (artifact from the original copy and paste).  I've tried all the capitalization.  I'll look at the data type problems

Comment: further tinkering with capitalizations got it working